# How to change the labels names in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I have created a graph with networkx library and I have a list called node_labels :

```
G = nx.Graph()

edges= [(1,2),(1,3),(2,4),(2,5),(5,6)]

G.add_edges_from(edges)

nodes_labels = { "A":1 , "B":2 , "C":3, "D":3 , "C":4 , "D" : 5 , "E" : 6 }

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```

I'm wondering how I can have A,B,C,D and E instead of 1,2,3,4 and 5 as the graph labels shown.

Answer (score 0):

Your labels have to map node IDs to names, so invert your dictionary:

```
node_labels = {v : k for k,v in nodes_labels.items()}
```

Then you can simply pass those labels as an argument to draw:

```
nx.draw(G, labels=node_labels)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. would you please rewrite the code  ```node_labels = {v : k for k,v in nodes_labels.items()}``` in non functional format?